# How to add a service registry (example: UDDI) to FuseESB?

Tags: web-services, service-discovery, uddi, fuseesb

I'm using Red Hat Fuse ESB.

I would like to use the "service registry" concept (example: UDDI) for discovery at run time the endpoint of the service.

It is feasible?!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This question is being discussed here, where the question was first asked
http://fusesource.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4655&tstart=0